# Splitting a string up into sentences by common punctuation

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently running into trouble with what I thought would be a simple task.

If I have a string like:

Sentence 1 “double quoted phrase” sentence 1.  Sentence 2?  Sentence 3 (numbers in parentheses like 1.2 should not be split).  Sentence 4 ' single quoted phrase. rest of quote' sentence 4. Sentence 5!

I want to split it into:

Sentence 1 “double quoted phrase” sentence 1.

Sentence 2?

Sentence 3 (numbers in parentheses like 1.2 should not be split).

Sentence 4 ' single quoted phrase. rest of quote' sentence 4.

Sentence 5!

Obviously a simple `"\.|\?|!"` match won't work. Any help is appreciated.

I realize regexes might not be the best tool for this, but unless there's another quick easy solution that I'm missing, I'm past the point of no return.

Comment: What is the tool/language?

Comment: @Kent PHP using regexes.

Comment: @Phil as long as your language supports regex subsitution, you could translate the sed line into your language. but read the rest comments in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex

```
(?:^|\s).+?[.!?](?:\s|$)
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me, I'm not literally matching text that says Sentence.

Comment: @Phil so what is the criteria for splitting?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is a job for regex.

but take a look this regex (with sed):

```
 sed -r 's/([.?!]) +([A-Z])|\1$/\1\n\2/g' file
```

it outputs:

```
Sentence 1 “double quoted phrase” sentence 1.
Sentence 2?
Sentence 3 (numbers in parentheses like 1.2 should not be split).
Sentence 4 ' single quoted phrase. rest of quote' sentence 4.
Sentence 5!
```

However it is not perfect. If you change the `rest` in sentence 4 to `Rest` it fails.

The problem is, you have to check, if the `.!?` wrapped by `"",'',(),[],{}....` it is not an ending of sentence. However the worse part is, for example, I would write a sentence:

```
The dot ". is a period.
```

notice that I forgot (a mistake) the closing quote. or the following (two sentences):

```
Why not put a brace "(" there ? The closing brace ")" is missing its partner.
```

How can your program (by regex) know this should be two sentences?